# How to authenticate to Google Cloud API without Application Default Credentials or Cloud SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, gcloud, google-cloud-nl

I'm trying to access the Google Cloud API from an AWS Lambda function but I don't know how to authenticate. The auth guide in the Google Cloud documentation (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) wants me to download a credentials JSON file and use Application Default Credentials, but as anyone who has used hosted functions already knows, the point is that you don't need to manage a server or runtime environment, so Lambda doesn't give me the ability to store arbitrary files in the environment of the running code.

I can use the Cloud SDK locally to get an access token but it expires so I can't use it in my function as a permanent solution.

Is there not a way I can get an access token that I can use indefinitely in my code to call the Google Cloud API? Is there any other solution?

Comment: What language you are programming in? What google api library you using?

Comment: My AWS Lamba function is written in Javascript on Node JS and I'm calling Google's Natural Language APIs.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs to manage credentials?

Comment: That library is an implementation of Application Default Credentials and still requires you to download the JSON credentials file, which I cannot do in the AWS Lambda function environment.

Comment: Yes, I assume you would download that JSON key file, and embed its content in your code. You do not need to load it from a file, one can hardcode the credentials assuming your code is secure.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of hard-coding the content in the code. I kept digging and found the answer in an obscure link. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found how to hard-code the credentials without the need to save them in a JSON file. It was in this documentation here:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/language/0.7.0/guides/authentication

Below is an example that calls the Language API.

```
var language = require('@google-cloud/language')({
  projectId: '',
  credentials: {
      client_email: '',
      private_key: '',
  }
});

language.detectEntities('Axel Foley is from Detroit').then(function(data) {
  var entities = data[0];
  var apiResponse = data[1];
});
```

Comment: Actually what worked for me was to add it to the ImageAnnoatorClient. Adding it to the require of vision said that "require is not a function": var vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
    projectId: config.projectId,
    credentials: {
        client_email: config.clientEmail,
        private_key: config.privateKey
    }
});