# How do I use Google Cloud APIs without the SDK?

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am using the google cloud client libraries in C# and would like to if can run the release build of my project on another computer without the sdk installed. i.e just using an exe and the corresponding libraries.

Comment: seems to be duplicate. check out here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567548/how-to-authenticate-to-google-cloud-api-without-application-default-credentials

Comment: Yes, the Google Cloud Client libraries are just libraries. You don't need either the .NET SDK or the Google Cloud SDK to be installed in order to run your code. Have you already tried this and run into a problem of some kind? If so, please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!  After creating your program, if you don't want the additional library dlls to be hanging around, you'll need to merge them into your exe.  By default they are just outputted into your Debug / Release directory (where the exe resides).

To merge them all together, personally I've used Fody Weaver alot, it's very simple and did everything automatically for me: https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Alternatively on big projects I've used ILMerge as well, more on that's already been answered here: [Merge DLL into EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe)

Comment: The OP wasn't asking about merging the DLLs as far as I can tell - they do say "just using an exe and the corresponding libraries".